# Custom query using DB::select() on laravel 4.2 controller

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I had used a custom query in my controller in laravel here is my code in my controller:

```
public function c_viewSystemUser()
{
    $title = "View System Users";

    $jSu = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT dbo_systemusers.SystemUserID,dbo_systemtypes.SystemType, dbo_systemusers.SystemUserName INNER JOIN dbo_systemtypes ON dbo_systemusers.SystemUserTypeID = dbo_systemtypes.SystemUserTypeID"));

    return View::make('ssims.view_systemUser',compact('title','jSu'));
}
```

I wanted to display its result in my blade file view_systemUser

here is my code inside the view:

```
@if ($jSu)

<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="detailTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>System User ID</th>
            <th>SystemUser Type ID</th>
            <th>System UserName</th>
            <th>System User Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($jSu as $vu)
            <tr>

                    <td>{{ $vu->dbo_systemusers.SystemUserID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vu->dbo_systemtypes.SystemType }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vu->dbo_systemusers.SystemUserName}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vu->dbo_systemusers.SystemUserDescription}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>

</table>
```

And I am having an error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$dbo_systemusers (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel3\app\views\ssims\view_systemUser.blade.php)

Any suggestions?

Comment: im fairly new to laravel 4.2 sorry if i had a lot of question lately

Comment: Can i see the output of `print_r($jSu);`?

Comment: i tried removing the table then added `print_r($jSu)` heres what i got  `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [SystemUserID] => 1 [SystemType] => admin [SystemUserName] => 11388242 [SystemUserDescription] => This is me, shamvil )`

Comment: Try my answer. You don't use **.** dot notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach ($jSu as $key => $vu)
   <tr>

      <td>{{ $vu->SystemUserID }}</td>
      <td>{{ $vu->SystemType }}</td>
      <td>{{ $vu->SystemUserName}}</td>
      <td>{{ $vu->SystemUserDescription}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No prob. :D Glad could help you

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to join dbo_systemusers with dbo_systemtypes. 
Try this code

```
SELECT dbo_systemusers.SystemUserID,dbo_systemtypes.SystemType, dbo_systemusers.SystemUserName from dbo_systemusers INNER JOIN dbo_systemtypes ON dbo_systemusers.SystemUserTypeID = dbo_systemtypes.SystemUserTypeID
```

And Try this on View page

```
 @foreach ($jSu as $vu)
        <tr>

                <td>{{ $vu->SystemUserID }}</td>
                <td>{{ $vu->SystemType }}</td>
                <td>{{ $vu->SystemUserName}}</td>
                <td>{{ $vu->SystemUserDescription}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```